# Problems using SQL ALL operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble using/understanding the SQL ALL operator. I have a table FOLDER_PERMISSION with the following columns:

```
+----+-----------+---------+----------+
| ID | FOLDER_ID | USER_ID | CAN_READ |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+
|  1 |     34353 |   45453 |        0 |
|  2 |     46374 |  342532 |        1 |
|  3 |     46374 |   32352 |        1 |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+
```

I want to select the folders where all the users have permission to read, how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation and `having`:

```
select folder_id
from t
group by folder_id
having min(can_read) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer seems better but for the sake of completeness, using `ALL` a query could look like:

```
SELECT x1.folder_id
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    fp1.folder_id
                    FROM folder_permission fp1) x1
       WHERE 1 = ALL (SELECT fp2.can_read
                             FROM folder_permission fp2
                             WHERE fp2.folder_id = x1.folder_id);
```

If you have a table for the folders themselves replace the derived table (aliased `x1`) with it.

But this only respects users present in `folder_permissions`. If not all users have a reference in that table you possibly won't get the folders *really* all users can read.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to return the full matching records, you could try using some exists logic:

```
SELECT ID, FOLDER_ID, USER_ID, CAN_READ
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.FOLDER_ID = t1.FOLDER_ID AND t2.CAN_READ = 0);
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

The existence of a matching record in the above exists subquery would imply that there exist one or more users for that folder who do not have read access rights.

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation :

```
SELECT fp.FOLDER_ID 
FROM folder_permission fp
GROUP BY fp.FOLDER_ID 
HAVING SUM( can_read = 0 ) = 0;
```

You can also express it :

```
SELECT fp.FOLDER_ID 
FROM folder_permission fp
GROUP BY fp.FOLDER_ID 
HAVING MIN(CAN_READ) = MAX(CAN_READ) AND MIN(CAN_READ) = 1;
```